# loading a function in codeigniter returns 404 was not found on this server

Tags: php, codeigniter

in my codeigniter project my controller is located in this folder
**xxx\controllers**. I am attempting to call login_public controller to call the index method of the controller to load a view using the below approach

```
href="<?php echo base_url('rootfolder/login_public') ?>" >Create </a>
```

this returns an error **404 that rootfolder/login_public** was not found on this server.

Please what could be wrong. Does anyone have a better idea

Comment: What is rootfolder and what's it's path? And what's the full path of gbyte_global_app from the CI application folder? If you have changed the default layout for the app, what's the new layout?

Comment: the full path folder is myfeel.com/gbyte_global_app/controllers. Have not changed the default layout of the application

Comment: Have you changed the application folder name in "index.php"? By default CI expects the controllers in a folder named "application", but from your question, the controller seems to lie in a folder named "gbyte_global_app"

Comment: under which folder are you referring this index.php. I have index.php as a controller in the controller folder. Which index.php are u referring to

Comment: The main index.php file at the root of the CI folder

Comment: $application_folder = "gbyte_global_app"; its changed before now

Comment: Have you set the correct site base URL in your config file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139051/discussion-between-parker-and-peter-m).